# Closing all open streams in GRPC-Java from client end cleanly

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I am using GRPC-Java 1.1.2.  In an active GRPC session, I have a few bidirectional streams open.  Is there a way to clean them from the client end when the client is disconnecting?  When I try to disconnect, I run the following look for a fixed number of times and then disconnect but I can see the following error on the server side (not sure if its caused by another issue though):

**disconnect from client**

```
while (!channel.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
// check for upper bound and break if so
}
channel.shutdown().awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**error on server**

```
E0414 11:26:48.787276000 140735121084416 ssl_transport_security.c:439] SSL_read returned 0 unexpectedly.
E0414 11:26:48.787345000 140735121084416 secure_endpoint.c:185]        Decryption error: TSI_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to close gRPC (server-side or bi-di) streams from the client end, you will have to attach the rpc call with a `Context.CancellableContext` found in package `io.grpc`.

Suppose you have an rpc:

```
service Messaging {
    rpc Listen (ListenRequest) returns (stream Message) {}
}
```

In the client side, you will handle it like this:

```
public class Messaging {
    private Context.CancellableContext mListenContext;

    private MessagingGrpc.MessagingStub getMessagingAsyncStub() {
    /* return your async stub */
    }

    public void listen(final ListenRequest listenRequest, final StreamObserver<Message> messageStream) {

        Runnable listenRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Messaging.this.getMessagingAsyncStub().listen(listenRequest, messageStream);
            }

        if (mListenContext != null && !mListenContext.isCancelled()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "listen: already listening");
            return;
        }

        mListenContext = Context.current().withCancellation();
        mListenContext.run(listenRunnable);
    }

    public void cancelListen() {
        if (mListenContext != null) {
            mListenContext.cancel(null);
            mListenContext = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `cancelListen()` will emulate the error, 'CANCELLED', the connection will be closed, and `onError` of your `StreamObserver<Message> messageStream` will be invoked with throwable message: 'CANCELLED'.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `shutdownNow()` it will more aggressively shutdown the RPC streams you have.  Also, you need to call `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()` before calling `awaitTermination()`.

That said, a better solution would be to end all your RPCs gracefully before closing the channel.